# Getting Wordpress post_date field to match scheduled post time in CRON

Tags: wordpress, cron, publish

We manage a site for a client that posts news articles daily. Sometimes the authors will create a new article in the evening and schedule it to go out in the morning. I thought this would set the post_date to the scheduled publishing time, but instead it sets it to the time the article was *created* and then WP CRON published it at the specified time.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but on the site, we display the amount of time since the post was published, subtracting get_the_date() from the current time. So you'll see the article headline, and then some text like "published 12 minutes ago" or "published 2 hour ago."

This is a problem because articles created the night before will say "published 10 hours ago," even though the CRON activated the post 5 minutes ago, which is the time we need to use to make our calculations.

What I need is for the post_date to match the date/time at which the CRON published the story. Before I get frustrated going down a rabbit hole to figure this out, I was wondering if anyone has tackled this issue, or if anyone has tips for how to accomplish this (hooks to use, some code - pseudo or actual that might point me in the right direction, etc.). Any assistance would be most appreciated!

Comment: The `post_date` *created_time* could be valuable historical information for administrative or other purposes. Rather than destroying that information you could create a post_meta field to capture the *publish_date* and use that post_meta value for your **published X minutes ago** calculation. The function triggered by WP-Cron could add this post_meta field. If you need help with the code, please post your WP-Cron action hook function and any other relevant information.

Comment: That's a great idea! In fact, I could just add a field to posts via ACF that allows authors to add a custom publish date, and to use that for calculations instead of post_date if the field isn't empty. This way, I don't need to run background processes. Just let them decide if they want to use a different date for calculations or not. Genius! Thanks for the insights @kofeigen :)